# How to submit request to API via asihttprequest

Tags: c#, ios

I want to submit an API form via ios apps using ASIHTTPREQUEST . my problem is when I click the submit or send button nothing happens . I have done connect the send button to my view controller . Actually the thing that I want to do is messaging application by using my own hosting server which must post the uuid and password value to submit the request . Here is my implementation code .

```
      - (IBAction)sendClicked:(id)sender {

    [sendButton resignFirstResponder];
     {        
   ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL          URLWithString:@"https://cc.frifon.net_dosmssend/"]];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:3];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];  
[request setPostValue:USERNAME forKey:@"sip"];
[request setPostValue:PASSWORD forKey:@"pwd"];
[request setPostValue:UUID forKey:@"uuid"];
[request setPostValue:API_PASSWORD forKey:@"key"];
[request setPostValue:messageText forKey:@"message"];
[request setPostValue:NUMBER forKey:@"to"];
[request setPostValue:@"Submit" forKey:@"submit"];
[request start];
nil;

   [request startAsynchronous];
    NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    messageText.text = response;}
    }
    }
     @end
```

I also want to get the list of messages that has been send. A huge thanks for those who reply to this question .

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest has been discontinued for a while now... It would be a good idea to look into alternative libraries such as AFNetworking for better support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read the error properties just after StartAsynchronious. You must wait receive the messages from the delegate protocol of ASIHTTP

Implement this protocol on your class

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
   NSLog(@"Response %d ==> %@", request.responseStatusCode, [request responseString]);
}
```

You can also handle other methods if you choose, such as:

```
- (void)requestStarted:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help . I've done put that request but its told me that  use of undeclared identifier 'requestFinished'. How am I suppose to declare that ? here again my code :

                   [request startAsynchronous];

    
    - (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSError *error = [request error];
 if (!error) {
  NSString *response = [request responseString];
  messageText.text = response;
    }
    
    }

Comment: Are you declare the response of the protocol <ASIHTTPRequestDelegate> in your interface  ?